# Delete Rows based on a String that adresses to the range I need to delete

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, rows

I'm trying to delete a Range in vba. The range I need to delete consists of several rows. The numbers of these rows are stored in an array variable named rowsDelete. Also, I built a string variable named rngString that points to the adress of these rows.

The integer array rowsDelete has the value [2,3,4,6,7,8,10]
The string rngString has the value "2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 6:6, 7:7, 8:8, 10:10, (...), 72:72"

I'm trying this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(rngString).Delete
```

But I'm getting an error related to object definition at this line.

The entire code is as bellow:

```
Sub edita_tabela_suno()
'
' edita_tabela_suno Macro
'
Dim rng, rngDelete As Range
Dim arrayDimension As Integer
Dim rowsDelete() As Integer
Dim size As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim msg, rngString As String
'
    Set rng = Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    arrayDimension = rng.Rows.Count
    k = 0
    size = (arrayDimension \ 4) * 3 + (arrayDimension Mod 4) - 1
    ReDim rowsDelete(size)
        
    
    For i = 1 To arrayDimension
        If i Mod 4 <> 1 Then
            rowsDelete(k) = i
            k = k + 1
        End If
        
    
    
    Next
    
    For j = LBound(rowsDelete) To UBound(rowsDelete) - 1
        msg = msg & rowsDelete(j) & vbNewLine
        rngString = rngString & CStr(rowsDelete(j)) & ":" & CStr(rowsDelete(j)) & ", "
    Next j
        rngString = rngString & CStr(rowsDelete(j)) & ":" & CStr(rowsDelete(j))
    'MsgBox "the values of my dynamic array are: " & vbNewLine & msg
    MsgBox rngString
    Set rngDelete = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(rngString)
    rngDelete.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYmfx.png)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the value of `rngString`? A quick test worked for me.

Comment: At a guess you have one extra index with a 0 value, the last `next j` pushes the final concatenation into that index which then adds a 0:0 and there is no row 0, though I'd imagine you'd see that in the `msgbox`.

Comment: Hi @SJR, I checked it, yes (I'll update the question with the rngString value, for reference.

Comment: @Warcupine, I did check the rngString in the msgbox command, but it shows no zeros; I'll update the post with the image. Thanks for now!

Comment: Can you paste into your question rather than as a picture? There might be a size limit.